# SQL execute substring expression dynamically from metadata

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, substring, dynamic-sql

I have substring expressions stored in a metadata table like so that maps to different columns in a table.

```
Stagingtable:
Rawdata
T300 Apples

Columnmapping
Splitfunction            TABLEID    column     tablemappingchar
SUBSTRING (RAWDATA,1,1)    1         datatype     t
SUBSTRING (RAWDATA,2,3)    1         datavalue    t
SUBSTRING (RAWDATA,,5,10)  1         dataname     t

 Tablemapping
TableId   tablename
 1       datavalues
```

I load the raw data into the staging table and then would like to use the Metadata split functions to map the data to the final tables and columns.

I'm using dynamic SQL as that was what I'd expect would perform the split functions in the output

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar (1000) = n' select replace(splitfunction,''rawdata'',st.rawdata) as columndata
Tableid,tablename,column
 From tablemapping tm
 Join columnmapping cm on cm.tableid=tm.tableid
 Join staging st on substring(st.rawdata,0,1)=cm.tablemappingchar

'
Exec (@sql)
```

I'm expecting the output to do the substring functions and the result of the dynamic sql should be:

```
Columndata  tableid  tablename    column

 T           1        datavalues   datatype
 300         1        datavalues   datavalue
 apples      1        datavalues   dataname
```

Where am I going wrong? 
The output just is throwing me back the explicit text of the split function like this but is not doing the function

```
  Substring ('t300 apples',1,1)
  Substring ('t300 apples',2,3)
  Substring ('t300 apples',5,10)
```

Can this not be done with dynamic sql?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Instead of exec(@sql) put in "print @sql", then copy that string and execute it in another window. Is it the string you want? Does it behave as expected?